# rabbitmq + phalconphp as consumer (with background jobs)

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, phalcon, php-amqp

How to connect phalconphp as consumer with rabbitmq?

As I understood I need to have a background process running for phalconphp to be able to listen for events/messages from rabbitmq and process some time intensive tasks (sending mail, writing to logs).

What would fire the consumer (in Phalcon), maybe supervisord?

I found some article that states just to run **php worker.php** containing a listen method:

http://www.sitepoint.com/php-rabbitmq-advanced-examples/

Answer (score 2):

While just running php worker.php will work, if you don't use a supervisor service, and just use a while(1) and send it to the background, there is no way to handle the process dying.

supervisord is recommended because you need to daemonize the process, and ensure that if it dies, or if the system is rebooted, that the process will be restarted.

You might also want to check into upstart. It can achieve the same goal.